# Rhythmbox not saving imported files & other issues

Tags: music, rhythmbox, ipod

I've recently changed PC & transferred my music folders over, but I've got noticed some issues with Rhythmbox (using ubuntu 12.10):

1) When music is imported where is it saved? I imported music from an external HDD to rhythmbox & want it all to be saved in artist/album folders in 'Music' but can't get it to do so. Files show up in rhythmbox but I don't know where they're saved to. I'm doubtful if the import is permanent too as I'd imported previously but when I logged on today rhythmbox was empty.

2) I've tried to set Preferences>Music>Music Location as the 'music' folder I want but it keeps showing 'multiple locations set'. How do I change this & ensure imported files/folders are saved where I want

3) I've got plugins enabled for album art getting but can't see how to get this to work?

4) Trying to answer the above I went to the rhythembox site & saw http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/screenshots/rhythmbox-visualization.png
Can't see any way to set up visualizations on rhythembox but it looks cool so I'd like to know how.

5) I now find that I've got some files on my Ipod I don't have in my external HDD music folder as for some reason importing these into rhythmbox previously didn't save them - Will I be able to transfer from Ipod to Rhythembox  save them in my main music folder?

I realise its a lot of questions but I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rhythmbox doesn't copy your music to a different folder when you add files to your library. It stores the reference to the file you added, and some of the information from its ID3 tags, and that is all. If you added a bunch of files on an external disk, then unmounted the disk, the tracks will be hidden from the library view, and will show up under the "Missing files" source that will appear in the left hand panel.

The "multiple locations set" for the library folder is because purchased music from Ubuntu One gets downloaded to a separate folder, and not in the Music folder, so the plug-in adds the correct location to the library locations list. The otherwise standard default location, is your standard "Music" folder. If you pick a different location, then the new location will be used, and the Ubuntu One extension will ensure its location is also added to the list. However, as I already said, Rhythmbox does not copy music over to another directory when you import it.

The Cover Art Search plug-in will search for album art using last.fm, and cache it locally. It will also look inside the tags in the music file. If it can't find art for the song, it won't display it.

If you drag a song from your iPod to the "Music" library in Rhythmbox, then it will copy that file to your local music library folder. It does this because it knows the iPod is a music player. It doesn't do this for simple external disk drives, though.

Comment: Thanks, I see ripping cds via rhythmbox also saves the music files to the music folder, its just file imports it doesn't do this for. Ok, looks like I've just got a bit more manual file management inorder to keep my music stored in one location.

Cover art search doesn't seem to be displaying anything for any of my music - do I need to be signed into last fm for it to work?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. Cover Art Search doesn't do the display of the art. It just does lookups. I think there may be some bugs in Rhythmbox with cover art still. It's not showing some cover art for me, even though the images are embedded in the MP3's ID3 tags.

Comment: Yeah, I see the actual files have art associated with them but it doesn't come up on Rhythmbox - or transfer over to the Ipod. Looks like I'll need to hunt about for som other app to get art onto the Ipod. Thanks for your help dobey.